# Unir subconsultas con campos calculados

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo dos subconsultas en las cuales hago un campo calculado que me une un número de vuelo y la fecha.

Necesito unir ambas subconsultas mediante este campo calculado pero no sé cómo.

Intenté hacerlo mediante un `join` pero en el momento de relacionar los campos no sé cómo llamar al campo calculado, ya que no me toma el alias de la tabla *DATA_TIEMPOS_AJE_AV*

```
SELECT FECHA,FLIGHT, ORIGEN, VUELO, AIRCRAFT, CONCAT(CONVERT(INT,FECHA),FLIGHT) as N1
FROM DATA_TIEMPOS_AJE_AV
JOIN
(SELECT AEROLINEA,
 CONCAT(CONVERT(INT,CONVERT(DATETIME,FECHA_DE_SALIDA_REAL)),N_VUELO_LLEGANDO) AS N2
 FROM DATA_VUELOS_AVH) AEROLINEA_AV ON DATA_TIEMPOS_AJE_AV.N1= AEROLINEA_AV.N2
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] para ganarte tu primera medalla y leer [ask]. Cuando haces una pregunta en SQL, es importante tener un escenario reproducible, para obtener respuestas más eficaces. Si a la pregunta la acompañas de las sentencias de creación de las tablas con las columnas representativas, y de una inserción de datos de ejemplo, con el resultado esperado, puedes obtener unas soluciones mucho mejores, que cuando no se aporta esto.

Answer (score 0):

En este caso el `JOIN` es entre una tabla y una subconsulta, utilizando para vincular un campo calculado en ambas partes (solo mostrará información de las filas en los que el valor de ambos campos coincida).

No puedes utilizar el alias de una columna de una tabla en el JOIN debido a que esa columna no existe en la tabla (En este caso N1 no existe en DATA_TIEMPOS_AJE_AV). El alias pertenece a la query (solamente existe durante la duración de la misma).

Lo que si puedes hacer es utilizar la expresión en el `JOIN`, en este caso: `CONCAT(CONVERT(INT, DATA_TIEMPOS_AJE_AV.FECHA), FLIGHT)`.

En el caso de la subconsulta si puedes utilizar el alias de la columna, porque dicha columna está definida en la misma. En este caso no podrías utilizar la expresión porque la columna FECHA_DE_SALIDA_REAL no pertence a la subconsulta (pertence a la tabla DATA_VUELOS_AVH).

```
SELECT FECHA, FLIGHT, ORIGEN, VUELO, AIRCRAFT, CONCAT(CONVERT(INT, FECHA), FLIGHT) AS N1
FROM DATA_TIEMPOS_AJE_AV
JOIN
    (SELECT AEROLINEA, CONCAT(CONVERT(INT,CONVERT(DATETIME, FECHA_DE_SALIDA_REAL)), N_VUELO_LLEGANDO) AS N2
    FROM DATA_VUELOS_AVH) AS AEROLINEA_AV ON CONCAT(CONVERT(INT, DATA_TIEMPOS_AJE_AV.FECHA), FLIGHT) = AEROLINEA_AV.N2
```

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que la manera más eficaz sea dejar a SQL Server que trabaje las dos consultas de un modo independiente, y se unan por los resultados.

```
Select FECHA
     , FLIGHT
     , ORIGEN
     , VUELO
     , AIRCRAFT
     , TIEMPOS_AV.N1
     fROM (
        Select FECHA
             , FLIGHT
             , ORIGEN
             , VUELO
             , AIRCRAFT
             , CONCAT(Convert(Int, FECHA), FLIGHT) As N1
           From DATA_TIEMPOS_AJE_AV
         ) AS TIEMPOS_AV
        Join 
         (
           Select AEROLINEA
                , CONCAT(Convert(Int, Convert(DateTime, FECHA_DE_SALIDA_REAL)), N_VUELO_LLEGANDO) As N2
              From DATA_VUELOS_AVH
         ) As AEROLINEA_AV On TIEMPOS_AV.N1 = AEROLINEA_AV.N2;
```

O mediante una tabla de expresión común correlativa.

```
WITH TIEMPOS_AV AS -- la sentencia anterior, si la hay, tiene que terminar en ;
(
    Select FECHA
             , FLIGHT
             , ORIGEN
             , VUELO
             , AIRCRAFT
             , CONCAT(Convert(Int, FECHA), FLIGHT) As N1
           From DATA_TIEMPOS_AJE_AV
), AEROLINEA_AV AS 
(
  Select AEROLINEA
                , CONCAT(Convert(Int, Convert(DateTime, FECHA_DE_SALIDA_REAL)), N_VUELO_LLEGANDO) As N2
              From DATA_VUELOS_AVH
)
SELECT FECHA
     , FLIGHT
     , ORIGEN
     , VUELO
     , AIRCRAFT
     , TIEMPOS_AV.N1
     FROM TIEMPOS_AV JOIN AEROLINEA_AV ON TIEMPOS_AV.N1 = AEROLINEA_AV.N2;
```

Además de que el plan de ejecución es probable que sea mejor, sobre todo lo notarás si hay gran cantidad de datos, en mi opinión, es mucho más legible la consulta de esta manera.